# How do I fix android builder error EvalissuesException in android studio

Tags: android

Am starting out my first Android project. I have encountered so many errors but i have been able to fix some but this one has become pain in the head. How can I go about it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXs16.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Jetifier on your project, which will basically exchange the Android Support Library dependencies in your project dependencies with AndroidX-ones. (e.g. Your Lottie dependencies will be changed from Support to AnroidX)

Android Studio Documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/)

Precondition for Jetifier:
you have to use at least **Android Studio 3.2**

To enable jetifier, add those two lines to your **gradle.properties** file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Finally, please check the release notes of AndroidX, because jetifier has still some problems with some libraries (e.g. Dagger Android): https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn